# How to make myURL clickable on all textviews of Android?

Tags: android, url

Is there a way to register a URL schema on Android so that it will automatically become a clickable link on any SMS, email or other textviews of any other applications on Android like web address, email address and telephone number?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. If you create the `doug://` scheme, you cannot cause other apps to honor it when they use `Linkify` or the equivalent.